# what's this bash redirection operator? "<<!"

Tags: bash

I saw the following bash code:`at 19:00 <<! echo "job 1"`. I have two problems:

1. What's this redirection operator: `<<!`?
2. I wrote the following script code:

   ```
   at 19:00 <<!
       echo "job 1"

   at 20:00 <<!
       echo "job 2"
   ```

   When I executed this script, `atq` command only showed one job, the first one. What's the matter? And how should I submit the two jobs via this script correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<<!` is a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections), as Nya explained.

You should write:

```
at 19:00 <<!
    echo "job 1"
!
at 20:00 <<!
    echo "job 2"
!
```

Without the lines starting `!`, your here document was the rest of the shell script, which is why there was only one command in the `atq`.  (But, the command would have scheduled the second job when it ran!)

Answer (score 6):

From [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)

> 3.6.6 Here Documents
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only word (with no trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input for a command.

```
The format of here-documents is: 
     <<[−]word
             here-document
     delimiter
```

So

1. You shouldn't need to specify anything after `word`(in your case `!`)
2. Then you should specify `at` job on one or more lines
3. Finally, add a line containing `word`(again, in your case `!`)

Comment: Note that I/O redirections, including here documents, can appear anywhere on the command line.  So, for example: `<file1 >>file2 sed s/x/y/g` is fully equivalent to `sed s/x/y/g <file1 >>file2`.  The pipe is slightly different; it marks the boundary between two commands.  However, you can write `sed s/x/y/g <<! | another-command` (followed by the here document).  Or you can leave the `another-command` off after the pipe, in which case the here document comes next, followed by the command into which the output is piped.