# bash: what is the difference between "done < foo", "done << foo" and "done <<< foo" when closing a loop?

Tags: bash, syntax, sh

In a bash script, I see several while statements with those redirect signs when closing the loop.
I know that if I end it with "done < file", I am redirecting the file to the stdin of the command in the while statement. But what the others means?

I would appreciate if someone could give an explanation with examples.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/342982/is-there-a-binary-safe-triple-less-than-operator-in-bash

Comment: I'd argue that this is two separate questions. If you were asking what `<<foo` was, or what `<<<foo` was, we already have knowledge base entries for both. Why should we have a third question that does nothing but combine two that already exist?

Comment: example for the first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837108/whats-this-bash-redirection-operator

Comment: example for the second: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036073/what-does-this-socat-command-do/36037427

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I don't actually think that's on-point as a duplicate here. That question is not asking about the syntax itself, but about being binary-safe, which has a different set of issues (ie. ability to contain NUL values, and avoiding automatic append of a trailing newline).

Comment: Related StackOverflow Documentation link: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/655/here-documents-and-here-strings#t=201611032106334924168

Comment: Can't you read the section of the `bash` manual on I/O redirection? https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did not vote to close because belongs to superuser. I was just giving a link. Good answers below BTW.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, ...I actually *do* think this question should be closed, but I don't think the superuser link is relevant in any respect. It's very rare for someone using heredocs or herestrings to care at all whether they're binary-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first form, `<`, is an [input redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). It somewhat different than `<<` and `<<<` which are two variants of a [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

The first form, `<`, is primarily used to redirect the contents of a file to a command or process. It is a named FIFO, and therefor a file that is passed to a command that accepts file arguments.

```
cmd < file
```

will open the file named `file` and create a new file name to open and read. The difference between `cmd file` and `cmd < file` is the name passed to `cmd` in the second case is the name of a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

You can also do process substitution:

```
cmd <(process)
```

An example use would be comparing two directories:

```
diff <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)
```

In this case, the command `ls dir1` and `ls dir2` has output redirected to a file like stream that is then read by `diff` as if those were two files.

You can see the name of the file device by passing to `echo` a process substitution:

```
$ echo <(ls)
/dev/fd/63
```

Since `echo` does not support opening files, it just prints the name of the FIFO.

Here documents are easier to demonstrate. The `<<` form has a 'limit string' that is not included in the output:

```
$ cat <<HERE
> line 1
> line 2
> line 3
> HERE
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

The `HERE` is a unique string that must be on its own line.

The 'here string' or `<<<` form does not require the delimiting string of the `<<` form and is on a single line:

```
$ cat <<< 'line 1'
line 1
```

You can also expand parameters:

```
$ v="some text"
$ cat <<< "$v"
some text
```

But not other forms of shell expansions:

Brace expansion:

```
$ echo a{b,c,d}e
abe ace ade
$ cat <<< a{b,c,d}e
a{b,c,d}e
```

Given a 'generic' Bash while loop that reads input line by line:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do printf "'%s'\n" "$line"; done
```

There are several ways that you can feed input into that loop.

First example, you can redirect a file. For demo, create a 6 line file:

```
$ seq 6 > /tmp/6.txt
```

Redirect the input of the file into the loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do printf "'%s'\n" "$line"; done </tmp/6.txt
'1'
'2'
'3'
'4'
'5'
'6'
```

Or, second example, you can directly read from the output of `seq` using redirection:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do printf "'%s'\n" "$line"; done < <(seq 3)
'1'
'2'
'3'
```

(Please note the extra `<` with a space for this form)

Or, third example, you can use a 'HERE' doc separated by CR:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do printf "'%s'\n" "$line"; done <<HERE 
1 
2 3
   4
HERE
'1 '
'2 3'
'   4'
```

Going back to `diff` which will *only* work on files, you can use process substitution and a HERE doc or process substitution and redirection to use `diff` on free text or the output of a program.

Given:

```
$ cat /tmp/f1.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Normally you would need to have a second file to compare free text with that file. You can use a HERE doc and process substitution to skip creating a separate file:

```
$ diff /tmp/f1.txt <(cat <<HERE
line 1
line 2
line 5
HERE
)
3c3
< line 3
---
> line 5
```

Comment: thanks, but why in a loop this is diferent? Why it is not: while cmd < file; do cmd2; done ?

Comment: @Lilás, because in `while cmd < file`, the `< file` is run every time `cmd` is, thus starting from the very beginning of the file on every invocation.

Answer (score 3):

With the file **text.txt**

```
1aa
2bb
3cc
```

Redirection:

```
$ cat < text.txt
1aa
2bb
3cc
```

Here document:

```
$ cat << EOF
> 1AA
> 2BB
> EOF  
1AA 
2BB
```

Here string:

```
$ cat <<< 1aaa
1aaa
```

Comment: Consider `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done` to avoid inadvertently teaching bad practices. Without the `-r`, backslashes in the input are silently consumed; without clearing IFS, trailing whitespace is silently deleted; without the quotes on the expansion passed to `echo`, a `*` in the input becomes a list of filenames, etc. [Granted, using `REPLY` moots the IFS concern, but it's not obvious to a reader that the lack of a named destination variable is the reason leading and trailing whitespace isn't trimmed, or that they can't use that practice with `#!/bin/sh`].

Answer (score 1):

```
command < foo
```

Redirect the file `foo` to the standard input of `command`.

```
command << foo
blah 1
blah 2
foo
```

Here document: send the following lines up to `foo` to the standard input of `command`.

```
command <<< foo
```

Here-string. The string `foo` is sent to the standard input of `command`.